# defimpl Phoenix.Param to override to_param causes (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Param.Rumbl.Video.to_param/1

Tags: phoenix-framework, web-development-server, elixir

`while` trying to follow the examples in [**Programming Phoenix** (book) release **P1.0**](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix), 
everything is working fine until **Page 167** when instructed to add the lines:

```
defimpl Phoenix.Param, for: Rumbl.Video do
  def to_param(%{slug: slug, id: id}) do
    "#{id}-#{slug}"
  end
end
```

to: `rumbl/web/models/video.ex`

Before I add the lines, the tests pass (*as expected*): 
https://travis-ci.org/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/builds/207894163#L384
[image: tests-pass]

But once the `defimpl` is added the tests fail: 
https://travis-ci.org/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/builds/207901757#L349

[image: tests-fail]

The error message for two of the failing tests is:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Phoenix.Param.Rumbl.Video.to_param/1
```

Stack trace: https://travis-ci.org/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/builds/207901757#L349
[image]

Code Snapshot when these 5 lines were added: 
https://github.com/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/pull/42/commits/db72acbe83b184cd6ce3fe342ee51c3e39eb5de8

Any help with *understanding* this would be *much* appreciated!

> Note: I've tried googling (*for a while*) ... 
>   I've read through dozens of similar-looking questions on SO & https://elixirforum.com ...  
>   but none were helpful. it appears I'm the only one seeing this error! 
>   Posting a StackOverflow question is my "last resort" before giving up programming! :-( 
>   [image: help me obi-wan]

On the "Programming Phoenix" book's errata page: https://pragprog.com/titles/phoenix/errata there is another person reporting an issue with the same code but their error is different ...

[image: errata-not-the-same]

Comment: It looks like your `Video` model doesn't have a `slug` field: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/blob/dc763cac1c6f9fc25f451635ca3a29483aad3a76/rumbl/web/models/video.ex. Does it work if you replace `slug` with `url` everywhere in the `defimpl`?

Comment: adding `field :slug, :string` to the `web/models/video.ex` got me down to 1 failing test: https://travis-ci.org/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/builds/207907120#L378  thanks @Dogbert! :-)

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/pull/42/commits/954fab878e9e3093fd040e172ee18d01ef82c26c https://travis-ci.org/dwyl/learn-phoenix-framework/builds/207910866#L416 thanks for your help @Dogbert